# I want to set wp_schedule_event specific time

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I went set wp_schedule_event at 00:01 AM daily. My code here:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp', 'cron_hookup' );
    /**
     * On an early action hook, check if the hook is scheduled - if not, schedule it.
     */
    function cron_hookup() {
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cron_funct' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'cron_funct');
        }
    }

    add_action( 'cron_funct', 'cron_order' );

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've been to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to get your code but maybe it just wasn't clear enough there. So I'll see what I can do.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'cron_hookup' );
function cron_hookup() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'prefix_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cron_funct');
    }
}
/** This code will setup the cron job to run daily */


add_action( 'cron_funct', 'prefix_do_this_daily' );
function prefix_do_this_daily() {
    // This is the code that will be done executed every day.
}
```

Also, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com might be a better place for questions like this.